# Why %x and %o are treated as unsigned int?

Tags: c

```
ram@ram:~/Desktop$ cc sample.c 

sample.c: In function ‘main’:

sample.c:7: warning: format ‘%o’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’
```

Comment: How would you like them to specify negative numbers?

Comment: @Ignacio Vanquez-Abrams: hex numers don't generally have negative numbers, and even not floating point numbers.

Comment: @Dani: Actually, it is possible to have floating point numbers in other radices, they just aren't usually used.

Answer (score 7):

Because they are specified as taking an `unsigned int`.

(No, really.)